# Add text after a special character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string which is punctuated and I would like to add `&thinsp;` after all symbols.

For example, this string:

```
Hi there, how are you ? Ok/not_ok !
```

I expect it to become like this:

```
Hi there,&thinsp; how are you ?&thinsp; Ok/&thinsp;not_&thinsp;ok !&thinsp;
```

I was thinking about the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function, but I'll need to call it lot of times for all symbols...

```
str.replace("/","/&thinsp;");
str.replace(",",",&thinsp;");
str.replace("!","!&thinsp;");
str.replace("?","?&thinsp;");
str.replace("_","_&thinsp;");
```

Is there an easier way to achieve this using only 1 function? I was thinking about regexp, something similar to this:

```
str.replace([/,!?_],<selection>+"&thinsp;");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use capturing group based regex. This would capture the special characters into a group. Later we could refer those captured characters by specifying the group index number along with the `$` symbol in the replacement part (*like `$1`, `$2`*).

```js
var s = "Hi there, how are you ? Ok/not_ok !"
alert(s.replace(/([\/,!?_])/g, "$1&thinsp;"))
```

Comment: You can avoid the overhead of a capture group by using `$&` instead of `$1`, FWIW.

Comment: really don't know that  js implement this feature. @T.J.Crowder Why you delete your answer?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yours had the ground covered, mine was nearly a duplicate. Figured what value it had could be served by the comment above. :-)